# not able to start Spring web application in Tomcat web Application manager

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat9, tomcat-manager

Can you please help me to deploy the war file into Tomcat web Manager. I created my own web application in my personal pc and worked as expected  and I am trying to deploy another pc using tom cat web application manager and I am facing below issue.

Thanks in advance.

I am using tomcat 9

java 8

Spring 5.2.5

ORACLE 11g

[image]

attaching logs also, ***like I am facing multiple exception***

```
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.836 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.40
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.941 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 12 2020 15:35:02 UTC
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.941 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.40.0
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.942 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.943 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.943 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.944 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.944 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_201-b09
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: abort
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.945 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
**01-Mar-2021 08:42:20.977 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat** 9.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]
01-Mar-2021 08:42:25.382 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
01-Mar-2021 08:42:26.734 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [7263] milliseconds
01-Mar-2021 08:42:27.016 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
01-Mar-2021 08:42:27.016 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.40]
01-Mar-2021 08:42:27.062 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs]
01-Mar-2021 08:42:29.768 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\docs] has finished in [2,702] ms
01-Mar-2021 08:42:29.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\host-manager]
01-Mar-2021 08:42:30.396 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [628] ms
01-Mar-2021 08:42:30.400 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
01-Mar-2021 08:42:30.782 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [382] ms
01-Mar-2021 08:42:30.786 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT]
01-Mar-2021 08:42:31.110 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [324] ms
01-Mar-2021 08:42:31.134 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
**01-Mar-2021 08:42:31.258 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [4516] milliseconds
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)**
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:880)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1601)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
01-Mar-2021 08:43:13.169 SEVERE [http-nio-8088-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/D:SoftwaresCocount_v1]
    java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\D:SoftwaresCocount_v1]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:958)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:182)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1642)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1596)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:212)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:880)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1601)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
01-Mar-2021 08:43:13.169 WARNING [http-nio-8088-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.postWorkDirectory Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\D:SoftwaresCocount_v1] for context [/D:SoftwaresCocount_v1]

01-Mar-2021 08:43:13.185 WARNING [http-nio-8088-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register Failed to register object [org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache@15248558] with name [Catalina:type=WebResourceRoot,host=localhost,context=/D:SoftwaresCocount_v1,name=Cache] during component initialisation
    javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property
        at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:680)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4966)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1642)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1596)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:212)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:880)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1601)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    01-Mar-2021 08:43:23.749 SEVERE [http-nio-8088-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\D:SoftwaresCocount_v1.war]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:706)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1642)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1596)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:212)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:667)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:880)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1601)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error starting the loader
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:432)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5028)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property
        at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:425)
        ... 51 more
01-Mar-2021 08:43:23.765 INFO [http-nio-8088-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\D:SoftwaresCocount_v1.war] has finished in [10,642] ms
```

Comment: Did you try to upload a WAR file with a colon (`:`) in its name?

Comment: From local it took, Like D:/software/example.war.              If that is the case how to upload war file in tomcat manager.

Comment: How did you deploy that WAR file? Did you upload the file (_WAR file to deploy_) or did you fill the section _Deploy directory or WAR file located on server_ of Tomcat Manager. My guess is: you used the latter and you inserted a Windows path as _"Context Path"_.

Comment: @Piotr P. Karwasz , this issue resolved, when I pasted the war into wepabb server started.